# Problem with GLFW linking, as it used in SharedLib (DLL)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, glfw

Environment : Visual Studio 2019.

I'm developing an Engine as a SharedLib (DLL) and I made an example that uses this DLL so I can launch the Engine. at this stage I have to add GLFW library to the engine, so I added GLFW as a submodule (git) to my project and built this library as a StaticLib (.lib) with static runtime sets to "On". and added GLFW as a reference in the engine as in the second picture below. the build of GLFW goes very well and I get GLFW.lib. so I added some functions of GLFW to the engine code like `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` at this point when I build the Engine I get weird linking errors for many functions except `glfwInit()`.

here is a picture of an example of one of my linking errors:
[image]

the project view:

[image]

Note: opengl32.lib already added to the engine in the Input in the Linker.

Please if you have any thoughts, I would appreciate it if you can share them

**EDIT**

Here is the full linker commandline:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the full linker commandline. Are you sure GLFW.lib is even being linked?

Comment: @Botje Why are people still writing out the linker flags out manually? Visual studio integrates with cmake, and with cmake its just `add_subdirectory(path/to/glfw)`, `target_link_libraries(myapp glfw)` at worst where you compile the entire library locally, everything else is handled for you besides setting some flags whether you want shared or dynamic library, whether you want documentation/tests to be built or not...

Comment: @Kaihaku Because visual studio presents itself as a nice safe cocoon that you can use without knowing a thing about commandline options.

Comment: @Botje and you don't need to. That's what IDE's are for. Using an IDE but then falling back to "I will do everything myself anyway" is bizarre.

Comment: About 10% of the C++ questions here are about integrating external libraries in one way or another. I can imagine that OP tried and failed with a prebuilt binary distribution and then went with a build from source instead.

Comment: @Botje yes I'm sure GLFW.lib is being linked. I edited the question with the linker commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Everyone for your help. I got relatively a solution and I want to share it with you in case someone fall in the same situation.

> Short Answer:

I converted the GLFW from static library to shared library while the building, and the linking errors just gone.

> Long Answer

I wrote a Premake script to generate the GLFW project with configuration set to `Shared Library` and `staticruntime` to `Off` [meaning (Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)) for Runtime Library in Visual Studio configuration]. beside some includes and defines (take a look at the script) and I linked the GLFW library to the engine and I copied the .dll to the location of Sandbox/example application based on the engine and everything works pretty fine.

here is the script in case:

```
project "GLFW"
kind "SharedLib"
language "C"

targetname ("glfw3")
targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-intermediate/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

files
{
    "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
    "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
    "src/internal.h",
    "src/glfw_config.h",
    "src/mappings.h",
    "src/egl_context.h",
    "src/osmesa_context.h",
    "src/wgl_context.h",
    "src/context.h",
    "src/init.c",
    "src/input.c",
    "src/monitor.c",
    "src/vulkan.c",
    "src/window.c",
    "src/context.c"

}

includedirs {
    "%{prj.name}/src",
    "%{prj.name}/include"
}

filter "system:windows"
    buildoptions { "-std=c11", "-lgdi32" }
    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "Off"
    

    files
    {
        "src/win32_platform.h",
        "src/win32_joystick.h",
        "src/win32_init.c",
        "src/win32_joystick.c",
        "src/win32_monitor.c",
        "src/win32_time.c",
        "src/win32_thread.c",
        "src/win32_window.c",
        "src/wgl_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c"
    }

    defines
    {
        "_GLFW_WIN32",
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS",
        "WIN32",
        "_WINDOWS",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE",
        "_GLFW_BUILD_DLL"
    }

    links{
        "kernel32.lib",
        "user32.lib",
        "gdi32.lib",
        "winspool.lib",
        "shell32.lib",
        "ole32.lib",
        "oleaut32.lib",
        "uuid.lib",
        "comdlg32.lib",
        "advapi32.lib"
    }

    postbuildcommands{
        ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../../../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox")
    }
    
filter { "system:windows", "configurations:Debug"}
    buildoptions "/MDd"
filter { "system:windows", "configurations:Release"}
    buildoptions "/MD"
```